# Custom validation help for laravel - check field against DB field

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

trying to think of a way to allow me to check an input password against that of the database.

For the database value I am using the Auth feature. So far I have:

```
$currentPassword = Auth::user()->password;
$passwordInput = Input::get('password-old');

if (isset($passwordPassword) && !Hash::check($passwordInput, $currentPassword))
{
return Redirect::to('/updatepassword')->with('incorrectPassword', '1');
}
```

I am then checking for the incorrectPassword sent with the redirect. This works, but its ugly. I want to create a custom validation where I can check the field against a given value.

So:

```
'password' = > 'checkMatch:$checkValue'
```

Or something?

Any help on this? I have looked at how to implement custom validation rules but cant get it into my head without a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Validator::extend('checkMatch', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
   if (count($parameters) < 1)
      throw new InvalidArgumentException("Validation rule checkMatch requires at least 1 parameters.");

   return Hash::check($value, $parameters[0]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, how would this be used? As in 'password' => 'required|checkMatch:?'

Comment: Yes, `'password' => 'required|checkMath:yourPasswordHere'`